# Autolayout ignoring one of the vertical layouts inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `UILabel`, a `UIView` and a `UIButton` vertically one after one inside UITableViewCell. All of them have top, leading, bottom and trailing constraint. Only the button doesn't have trailing constraint, instead it has height and width.

The error is:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you posted the error text instead of an image. You can go to [wtfautolayout](http://wtfautolayout.com) for some help, but my guess is that the sum of your vertical heights and constraints adds up to more than 44

Comment: What's wrong with sum of vertical heights going over 44? @Paulw11

Comment: You have a constraint that says that the overall height is 44 (The last one listed).  If the sum of the constraints is greater than 44 then the view can't be simultaneously 44 high and more than 44 high.

Answer (score 0):

If the button has heigh, width, top, bottom and leading constraints then the height and top + bottom constraints are redundant. You either need to delete the height constraint or one of bottom + top. Based on what you described in your question, I think this should solve your problem!